# Asymptotic for $(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^n$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm not sure but,

I guess (from my book) an asymptotic approximation of $(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^n$ would be

$$(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^n \space\space \to \space\space e^{-\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{2} + O(n^{-1/2})}$$ as n increases.

Can you explain to me why?

(That's just my guessing, so you can correct it)

Comment: By the Maclaurin series of $\log(1+x)$, $$
\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}} \right)^n  = n\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}} \right) = n\left( { - \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }} - \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{1}{{3n^{3/2} }} -  \ldots } \right)=\ldots
$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Wow. Thank you. It was kinda easy. I never thought it, though. Thank you.:)